# Asymptotic Distribution by Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots$ be i.i.d. exponential random variables with mean $1$ and variance $1$. Let $$Y_j=\sqrt{j}\left(X_j-1\right)$$
  for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$. I want to find the asymptotic distribution of $$\overline{Y}_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j.$$

Comment: @Did , what apply to this question? Sorry I didn't get what do u mean, thank you.

Comment: Quote: ... *mention what you tried, why this failed, which similar problems you can solve, and so on*. Unquote.

Comment: @Did My claim is that also in this case I have a Normal(0,2) distribution. I verified Lyaupounov condition and this implies Lindeberg. Hence I think I solved my problem. Thank you so much

Comment: The asymptotic variance is 1/2, not 2.

Comment: @Did, of course you are right...! Thank you again.

Comment: @Did Hi Did, indeed tonight I verified my computations for Lindeberg condition verification and I found a mistake. Are u able to provide such a verification? I would like to use the following CLT:

Comment: @Did  $$\underset{n\longrightarrow\infty}{lim}\frac{\underset{j=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}Y_{j}}{n}\overset{d}{\longrightarrow}N\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)
 $$

Comment: @Did and hence my Lyapaunov condition (that implies Lindeberg) is the following: $ \frac{1}{\left(\frac{n\cdot\left(n+1\right)}{2}\right)^{2}}\cdot\sum E\left[\mid Y_{k}\mid^{4}\right]=
 $ and from here I am not able to continue anymore. Do you have any idea?  Thank you, Thinker

Comment: Well, $E(Y_k^4)=O(k^2)$ hence the sum is $O(n^3)$, which, when divided by $n^4$, goes to zero.

Comment: @Thinker If you reached what you think is an acceptable solution, you might want to post it as an answer and, later on and if everybody seems to agree your solution is right, to accept it. Two advantages: first, the question does not stay open, second you will probably learn a lot writing down the solution.

Comment: @Did, I posted my proposed answer. Thank you, Thinker

Comment: Yep. +1. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 2):

If the assumptions of the central limit theorem with Lindeberg condition hold then:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}Y_{j}}{\sqrt{n\left(n+1\right)}}\overset{d}{=}N\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$

For each $ j\in\mathbb{N}$
  the variance of $Y_{j}$
  is $j$. We simply need to verify Lyapounov condition:
$$
\frac{1}{\left(\frac{n\cdot\left(n+1\right)}{2}\right)^{2}}\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}E\left[\mid Y_{k}\mid^{4}\right]\to0$$

Since  $\left(\frac{n\cdot\left(n+1\right)}{2}\right)^{2}$
  grows like  $n^{4}$
  and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}E\left[\mid Y_{k}\mid^{4}\right]$
  is $O\left(n^{3}\right)$, the condition is satisfied.